# Why one Iter<String> yeilds String while another yields &String while iterating?

Tags: rust

I am playing around with Rust trying to get a better understanding of how the reference works.

I have below code:

```
    let owned_arr: [String; 2] = ["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
    let ref_arra: &[String; 2] = &["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
```

Then I get the `iterator` as follows:

```
    let owned_arr: [String; 2] = ["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
    let ref_arra: &[String; 2] = &["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];

    let owned_iter: Iter<String> = owned_arr.iter();
    let ref_iter: Iter<String> = ref_arr.iter();
```

I noticed that both has type  `Iter<String>`.

Then instead of getting the iterator like this, I decided to use the for ... in syntax:

```
    let owned_arr: [String; 2] = ["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];
    let ref_arra: &[String; 2] = &["hello".to_string(), "world".to_string()];

    // let owned_iter: Iter<String> = owned_arr.iter();
    // let ref_iter: Iter<String> = ref_arr.iter();

    for i in owned_arr {
        let j: String = i;
        dbg!(j);
    }

    for i in ref_arr {
        let j: &String = i;
        dbg!(j);
    }
```

My question is, why is it that with `owned_arr: [String; 2]` the item retrieved in the `for .. in` is `String`, but for `&[String; 2]` the item retrieved is `&String` even though when the iterator of both is retrieved it comes out as `Iter<String>`. Why the difference then, when the iterator us used in a `for..in`?

Comment: `for` uses `into_iter`, not `iter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Iter<String>` is really `std::slice::Iter<'_, String>`. And it will return **references** to `String`s, not owned `String`s.

Secondly for loops use `IntoIterator` trait (see [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator)). Owned array returns a [`std::array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html) as it's iterator, but a reference to the array returns [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html). First one returns owned strings (as it consumes array) and the second one returns references to strings (as it borrows array).

Comment: What is the fundamental difference in it being `std::slice::Iter<'_, String>`? also is there a possibility to have know this would return a reference just from the type?

Comment: @FinlayWeber there are many types in standard library named `Iter`, so I thought this would be more explicit. As for your second question it is sometimes possible to guess (based on name and type, for example `std::slice::Iter` is generic over a lifetime, so it probably borrows some data, so it probably yields references).  But you can also look at the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator-for-Iter%3C%27a%2C%20T%3E) and see what is implementation of `Iterator` for `Iter`.